# Check if FormData is empty

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I have a form like this:

```
<form id="uploadimage" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">                   
    <div class="text-inside">
        Selectati Categoria<br><select id="sc" name="selectCat"></select><br><br>
        Nume Produs<br><input id="numprod" type="text" name="input-text" /><br>
        Pret Produs<br><input id="pretprod" type="number" name="input-pret" /><br><br>
        <input type="file" name="file"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="sumit" value="Send" id="imgButton" class="button"  /><br><br>
    </div>              
</form>
```

And I am trying to check is the filelds are empty in order to prevent the user from submiting empty fields so I used this:

```
$('#uploadimage').on('submit',(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    var name= $('#numprod').val();
    var pret = $('#pretprod').val();

    if(name && pret){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'connect.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(){
                alert('uploaded successuflly!');
            }
        });
    }else{alert('input fields cannot be left empty you num num!');}
}));
```

But I can still submit with no file selected and ajax is not reloading the page anymore. Any suggestions what can I do?

Comment: Short answer, you can't reliably. Longer answer: in Chrome and Firefox you can use `FormData.entries()` to retieve information, but these are not supported in older browsers and certainly not in IE. The alternative is to validate the form elements directly. Also note that you should remove `async: false` as its incredibly bad practice to use it

Comment: You're not checking the `file` field.

Comment: TheValyreanGroup done it, but the page still doesn't reload

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer, you can't reliably check that `FormData` contains information (as your original question asked).

In Chrome and Firefox you can use `FormData.entries()` to retrieve information, but these are not supported in older browsers and certainly not in IE.

The alternative is to validate the form elements directly - as you are doing - except that you missed out the `file` input. Also note that you should remove `async: false` as its incredibly bad practice to use it.

To fix your code, check the `val()` of the `file` input in the `if` condition:

```
$('#uploadimage').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $('#numprod').val().trim();
    var pret = $('#pretprod').val().trim();
    var file = $('input[type="file"]').val().trim(); // consider giving this an id too

    if (name && pret && file) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'connect.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: new FormData(this),
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(){
                alert('uploaded successuflly!');
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert('input fields cannot be left empty you num num!');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank Rory, it works, but I would like the page to reload after submit

Comment: `window.location.reload()`. Although that makes the point of the AJAX request pretty moot.

Answer (score 12):

As this is the top Google result, for anyone searching for a quick solution to checking whether a FormData object is empty, `FormData.entries()` will return an iterator. If you use the `.next()` method on that iterator, you will get an object with the properties `done` and `value`. Thus you can check for that `done` property to determine if the iterator has no entries. This worked for my needs:

```
formDataObject.entries().next().done
```

And a sandbox proof of concept: https://codesandbox.io/s/16v99w3o4 (check the console)

Comment: This is the right answer to the question

Answer (score 1):

Add an Id to the input of type file and check if it has files with the below snippet:

```
if(document.getElementById("file").files.length == 0 ){
    console.log("no files selected");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
formData.has('username'); // Returns false
formData.append('username', 'Chris');
formData.has('username'); // Returns true
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

I think you could also convert the data to a string and check the length.

```
surveyData.toString().length
```

No length, no data.